# Javascript suddenly not loading in only one of my pages. Works in others

Tags: javascript

I have been working on an application all day without any trouble. An hour ago the javascript on the page I've been working on the most stopped working.

I don't know what is causing the problem. I have looked over my code but can't see what is breaking it. I am using console.log in in each page to print a message to the Chrome developer console. The message is logged for other pages but not this one. There are no error messages shown.

I've tested all other pages with javascript in it and it works there. So it is not an issue with Chrome, but must be something  I did in the code.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block main %}
<div class="modal" id="journalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header" style="z-index:30">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="journal" value="" name="journal" style="height:50vh" value="" autofocus></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" style = "width: 100px" class="" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="split left">
    <div class="img-container centered-all">
        <img src='../static/img/img_splitscreen_01.jpg' style="width:400px">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="split right justify-content-center" id="taperForm">
    <div class="centered-vertically">
        <div style="width: 400px; margin: 0px auto">
            <div class ="form-group form-inline row justify-content-end">
                <label class="conrol-label col-sm-4">Select Date:</label>
                <input id="myDatepicker" class = "form-control col-sm-8" name="date" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-inline row justify-content-end">
                <label class= "conrol-label col-sm-4">Medication:</label>
                <select class = "form-control col-sm-8" name="drug" id="drug" autocomplete="off">
                    <option value ="None">Specify medication</option>
                    <option value="Abilify">Abilify</option>
                    <option value="Cymbalta">Cymbalta</option>
                    <option value="Epitec">Epitec</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row ml-auto justify-content-end">
                <button style="width:100%" type = "button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#journalModal">Write in journal</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group form-inline row justify-contents-end drug_data"  autocomplete="off">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Dose:</label>
                <input  type="number" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="dosage" autofocus name="dose"
                    style="width:40px" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0"
                     data-toggle="popover" data-animation="true" data-content="Enter your daily dosage in milligrams" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom">
               <label class="conrol-label col-sm-4">Mood:</label>
                <select class="form-control  col-sm-2" name="mood" id="mood" data-toggle="popover" data-animation="true" data-content="Enter your mood on a scale of 1 to 10" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom">
                    <option value = "0" >0</option>
                    <option value = "1">1</option>
                    <option value = "2">2</option>
                    <option value = "3">3</option>
                    <option value = "4">4</option>
                    <option value = "5">5</option>
                    <option value = "6">6</option>
                    <option value = "7">7</option>
                    <option value = "8">8</option>
                    <option value = "9">9</option>
                    <option value = "10">10</option>
                </select>
           </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group inline-form text-center drug_data" >
                <h6>Side Effects</h6>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="fatigue"  name="Fatigue" value="Fatigue">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Fatigue</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Weight-gain" value="Weight-gain">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">Weight-gain</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Weight-loss" value="Weight-loss">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Weight-loss</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Headache" value="Headache">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Headache</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Nausea" value="Nausea">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Nausea</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Sadness" value="Sadness">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Sadness</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Mania" value="Mania">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Mania</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/ -->
            <div class="Form-group row ml-auto justify-content-en drug_data">
                <button style="width:100%" type="button" id="submitAll">Update your Journey</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        console.log("connected")

        $.post("/gettaperdata", {date: $("#myDatepicker").val()}, function(data) {
        }).done(function(data){
           updateFields(data)
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error)
        });

        $("#myDatepicker").change(function(){
            $.post("/gettaperdata",{date: $("#myDatepicker").val()}, function(data) {
            }).done(function(data){
                updateFields(data)
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error)
            });
        })

        $('#submitAll').on("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault()
            // Get some values from elements on the page:
            var date = $("[name='date']").val()
            var drug = $("[name='drug']").val()
            var dose = $("[name='dose']").val()
            var mood = $("[name='mood']").val()
            var journal = $("[name='journal']").val()
            var side_effects_array =[]
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                side_effects_array.push($(this).val());
            });
            var side_effects = side_effects_array.join()
            var data = { date: date, drug: drug, dose: dose,  mood: mood, side_effects: side_effects, journal: journal}

            $.post("/tapercheck", data, function(data){
                $(location).attr('href',"/");
            }).done(function(){
                console.log("done")
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                // error handling
                alert("error")
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    });


    function updateFields(data) {
        let side_effects_array = data.side_effects.split(",")
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $("#drug").val(data.drug);
        $("#dosage").val(data.dose);
        $("textarea").html(data.journal);
        $("#modal-title").html(data.date);
        $("#mood").val(data.mood);
        console.log("testing")
        for (let i=0; i<side_effects_array.length; i++) {
            console.log(side_effects_array)
            document.getElementsByName(side_effects_array[i])[0].checked = true;
            console.log("in loop")
        }
        console.log("testing")
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @Pointy on the page in question nothing is happening. I am consol.loging on each page and and on this specific page nothing is logged, nothing that works through javascript is working on the page. (Tooltips, jquery requests, dynamic DOM changes, etc)

Comment: I don't think `onload` does anything in a `DIV`. That event only occurs for elements that load their contents remotely, like `img` and `script`.

Comment: Right, `div` elements will not emit a `load` event, as it doesn't load anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove that. I also have this  `$(document).ready(function() {`

        `console.log("connected")` Similar calls are emiting a log message log on my other pages

Comment: Is the console reporting any errors? A syntax error will completely prevent the code from running.

Comment: @Pointy The console is not printing any errors. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have error at the end of this function declaration. Remove semicolon and parenthesis at the end, you only need curly bracket at the end like this or put this function inside your `$(document).ready(function() {});`

```
function updateFields(data) {
            let side_effects_array = data.side_effects.split(",")
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $("#drug").val(data.drug);
            $("#dosage").val(data.dose);
            $("textarea").html(data.journal);
            $("#modal-title").html(data.date);
            $("#mood").val(data.mood);
            console.log("testing")
            for (let i=0; i<side_effects_array.length; i++) {
                console.log(side_effects_array)
                document.getElementsByName(side_effects_array[i])[0].checked = true;
                console.log("in loop")
            }
            console.log("testing")
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. Can you explain why i didn't get an error in the console?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure why you do not get error. Check your console settings maybe. 
I just have tried this code  and it throws: 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Maybe it can be because I separated this script in separated file and tested it that way.  Just guessing. :)